# Sort Numbers on Same Line, Remove Duplicates but Keep Original

Tags: bash

I have a file with pairwise combinations of numbers (1-3).

Example input:

```
2 1
3 1
1 2
3 2
1 3
2 3
```

What I would like to do is sort the numbers on the individual lines, and then remove most of the duplicates by keeping the original one.

Example output:

```
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

I have provided a simple example, but I plan to scale this up to pairwise combinations for 4+ numbers. If you think there is a better way to achieve the overall goal just let me know. Please let me know how to improve the question/title, or if there is a better exchange to put this question on. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk '$1>$2{$0=$2 OFS $1} 1' file1 | sort -u
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

`$1>$2{$0=$2 OFS $1}` sorts each line.  `sort -u` removes duplicate lines.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! Thanks for the explanation as well!